# NetworkX, Matplotlib GUI Application

Tags: matplotlib, networkx

Trying to write an application that repeatedly creates different graphs according to parameters that user inputs by means of a simple GUI.
All graphs together with some text describing them needs to be displayed in a single, one and the same Jupiter cell / window / chart redrawn with every new user input.

The code below is a simple Jupiter illustration of what to do:

```
import random
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

while input():
    i = random.randint(5, 10)
    G = nx.complete_graph(i)
    nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True)
    plt.show()
    print("Nodes data: ", G.nodes.data())
    print("Connected: ",list(nx.connected_components(G)))
```

In Jupiter running this loop results in a sequence of text and graph images on output:

[image]

```
Nodes data:  [(0, {}), (1, {}), (2, {}), (3, {}), (4, {}), (5, {}), (6, {}), (7, {}), (8, {}), (9, {})]
Connected:  [{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}]
```

[image]

```
Nodes data:  [(0, {}), (1, {}), (2, {}), (3, {}), (4, {})]
Connected:  [{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

And so on ...

Is it possible to redraw NetworkX + Matplotlib graphs and accompanying text in a single Jupiter cell or window of some other Python GUI framework?

Jupiter is not an absolute requirement for me, any other Python GUI will do also.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely possible (assuming I understood what you want to do correctly).
I would recommend using [ipywidgets](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to handle the GUI part.

See example below:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets

N_nodes_widget=widgets.IntSlider(min=1,max=100,value=5,step=1,continuous_update=False) #simple integer slider

def graph_generation(N_nodes):
  G = nx.complete_graph(N_nodes)
  nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True)
  print("Nodes data: ", G.nodes.data())
  print("Connected: ",list(nx.connected_components(G)))
  plt.show()
    
widgets.interact(graph_generation,N_nodes=N_nodes_widget); #interact function links slider to the graph generation function
```

[image]

### Edit:

In case, you want to keep the previous iterations of your graphs, you can store your graphs in a list and create a new figure of size (1,N_graphs) everytime the user interact with the widget. The information about the graph can be displayed in the title of the subplots. See example below:

```py
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets

N_nodes_widget=widgets.IntSlider(min=1,max=30,value=5,step=1,continuous_update=False)
list_plots=[] #create empty list of graphs

def graph_generation(N_nodes):
  G = nx.complete_graph(N_nodes)
  list_plots.append(G)
  fig,axs=plt.subplots(nrows=1,ncols=len(list_plots)) #create figure with N_graphs subplots
  for i, ax in enumerate(fig.axes):
    nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=True,ax=ax)
    ax.set_title("Nodes data:\n "+str(G.nodes.data()) + "\nConnected:"+str(list(nx.connected_components(G))),fontsize=6) #use title to print graph info
  plt.tight_layout()
  plt.show()
    
widgets.interact(graph_generation,N_nodes=N_nodes_widget);
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, ipywidgets - is exactly what I need !

Comment: Glad I could help! I also edited my answer to include the case where you might want to keep previously generated graphs in your figure.